# Cannot use CONFIG_CC_STACKPROTECTOR_STRONG: -fstack-protector-strong not supported by compiler

Tags: kernel, compiling, make

Trying to update kernel but I keep on getting `Cannot use CONFIG_CC_STACKPROTECTOR_STRONG: -fstack-protector-strong not supported by compiler` as a error... Im confused of the issue... full error below:

```
$ make oldconfig -j8 && make prepare -j8
scripts/kconfig/conf  --oldconfig Kconfig
#
# configuration written to .config
#
scripts/kconfig/conf  --silentoldconfig Kconfig
  CHK     include/config/kernel.release
Cannot use CONFIG_CC_STACKPROTECTOR_STRONG: -fstack-protector-strong not supported by compiler
Makefile:1098: recipe for target 'prepare-compiler-check' failed
make: *** [prepare-compiler-check] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: *** wait: No child processes.  Stop.
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using an old version of the compiler that does not support CC_STACKPROTECTOR_STRONG. Rather than editing the makefile itself, the proper way would have been to execute:

```
scripts/config --disable CC_STACKPROTECTOR_STRONG
```

as the first step.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up editing the makefile and commenting out a few lines for it.